# change QDir::rootPath() to program running path?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt FTP server that selects `C:/` as root path. I'm trying to change that to select the starting program location path.

For example: If ftpserver.exe is located in `H:/programs/ftpserver.exe`, it must automatically set the ftp root path to `H:/`.

Code:

```
ui->lineEditRootPath->setText(settings.value("settings/rootpath", QDir::rootPath()).toString());
```

Code:

```
void MainWindow::on_toolButtonBrowse_clicked()
{
    QString rootPath;
#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
    // In Android, the file dialog is not shown maximized by the static
    // function, which looks weird, since the dialog doesn't have borders or
    // anything. To make sure it's shown maximized, we won't be using
    // QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory().
    QFileDialog dialog;
    dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptOpen);
    dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
    dialog.showMaximized();
    dialog.exec();
    if (!dialog.selectedFiles().isEmpty()) {
        rootPath = dialog.selectedFiles().front();
    }
#else
    rootPath = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, QString(), ui->lineEditRootPath->text());
#endif
    if (rootPath.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    ui->lineEditRootPath->setText(rootPath);
}

void MainWindow::onPeerIpChanged(const QString &peerIp)
{
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Connected to " + peerIp);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonShowDebugLog_clicked()
{
    DebugLogDialog *dlg = new DebugLogDialog;
    dlg->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true );
    dlg->setModal(true);
    dlg->showExpanded();
}
```

Comment: Maybe `ui->lineEditRootPath->setText(settings.value("settings/rootpath", QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());` would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` returns the exact directory path of your app, for example `H:/programs` if your app path is `H:/programs/ftpserver.exe`
so if you modify that `QString` you can get the root dir.

For example:

```
QString rootPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath(); 
rootPath.chop(rootPath.length() - 3); //we leave the 3 first characters of the path, the root folder)
ui->lineEditRootPath->setText(rootPath); 
settings.setValue("settings/rootpath", rootPath);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i got this error: `no matching function for call to 'QLineEdit::setText(QVariant)'
     ui->lineEditRootPath->setText(settings.value("settings/rootpath", rootPath));`

Comment: I understand you want to set the root folder in the lineEditRootPath and in the settings class right? Then you have just to `ui->lineEditRootPath->setText(rootPath); settings.setValue("settings/rootpath", rootPath);` instead of `ui->lineEditRootPath->setText(settings.value("settings/rootpath", rootPath);`

Comment: i had to add `.toString` but current root path is still `C:/` i've tried on 2 PCs with different drives.

Comment: What do you get from `qDebug() << QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`??

Comment: Now is working perfectly thanks! your main answer must be changed. from `ui->lineEditRootPath->setText(settings.value("settings/rootpath", rootPath);`   TO  `ui->lineEditRootPath->setText(rootPath); settings.setValue("settings/rootpath", rootPath);`